# Cannot Retrieve Value of a Dynamically created EditText

Tags: android, android-edittext

Hi Guys I created some EditTexts dynamically from a JSON with a default value.

After entering some values to the EditTexts I accessed them using the **getChildAt()** method of the root view. When using the **getText()** method of the EditText it returned the default value, not the changed value. I could not even set the text of the EditText through code.

This is my method for creating the EditText.

```
private static EditText createEditText(final Context context,
        Element element) {
    final EditText editText = new EditText(context);
    editText.setId(Integer.parseInt(element.getFieldID()));
    editText.setText(element.getCellValue());
    editText.setTag(element);
    editText.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {

        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                KeyEvent event) {
            if (event != null
                    && (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                InputMethodManager inputMethodManager = (InputMethodManager) context
                        .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                inputMethodManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(
                        editText.getApplicationWindowToken(),
                        InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

    return editText;
}
```

And this is how I access the EditTexts after changing the text.

```
public static boolean updateElements(ScrollView rootView) {
    try {
        for (int i = 0; i < rootView.getChildCount(); i++) {
            View view = rootView.getChildAt(i);
            if (view.getClass() == LinearLayout.class) {
                LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view;
                for (int x = 0; x < layout.getChildCount(); x++) {

                    View linearView = layout.getChildAt(x);

                    if (linearView.getClass() == EditText.class) {
                        EditText txtBox = (EditText) linearView;

                        txtBox.setText("TextBox " + x);


                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return true;

    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

Please tell me what I'm doing wrong here...
Thank You.

Comment: Already tried. It returns the value set when the EditText was created. Not the changed value.

Comment: you can't use getChildAt() method on the linearView

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found the problem!!!

I've been setting the root view of the activity at both the **onCreate()** and the **onResume()** method. And the view that's being passed to the **updateElements(ScrollView rootView)** is the view created at the **onCreate()** method; but the the actual view shown is the view created on **onResume()**.

A rookie mistake! Anyway thanks for the help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change

```
Object.getClass() == Class.class
```

to

```
Object.getClass().equals(Class.class)
```

Comment: The problem is not there. I debugged and program goes inside the _if_ statement. The problem is that if i try to access the text it returns the default value set when the EditText was created. Not the changed text.

Comment: I cannot even set the text. There's no error.But its not shown in the view.

Comment: getText() method returns correct, updated value of the EditText. So it means, that you are trying to access not attached or invisible widget.

Comment: Yeah the getText() method usually does returns the correct value. But as said earlier it doesn't return the updated value in my case.And I have attached the EditText to the view. It is shown on the screen with the default value.

Comment: try to remove final modifier in "final EditText editText = new EditText(context);"